# How to Post to Facebook Page using Curl on SDK v4.1/5.00 2016 PHP API v2.5

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I got my permanent token following this guide: http://php8legs.com/en/facebook/41-how-to-auto-publish-post-on-facebook-fan-page-as-admin-using-facebook-php-sdk-v4-graph-api-v2-2-2-get-permanent-page-access-token

I installed Facebook SDK using composer.

I then struggled to find a proper script. If i use something like this: (removed the variable and the required)

```
$page_post = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/'. $page_id .'/feed', array(

    'access_token' => $access_token,

    'name' => 'Facebook API: Posting As A Page using Graph API v2.x and PHP SDK 4.0.x',

    'link' => 'https://www.webniraj.com/2014/08/23/facebook-api-posting-as-a-page-using-graph-api-v2-x-and-php-sdk-4-0-x/',

    'caption' => 'The Facebook API lets you post to Pages you administrate via the API. This tutorial shows you how to achieve this using the Facebook PHP SDK v4.0.x and Graph API 2.x.',

    'message' => 'Check out my new blog post!',

  ) ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();


// return post_id

print_r( $page_post );
```

well then it doesn't work I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'FacebookRequest' not found in..."

Comment: `it doesn't work because class FacebookRequest in FacebookRequest.php doesn't take argument` - this is false. PHP doesn't throw "Class not found" when you pass unexpected arguments to the constructor.

Comment: Just embed the autoloader that comes with the SDK at the very beginning of your script, then all classes will be loaded automatically when necessary.